# Flow Updates Library Column with ID from PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, flow

I am still in desparate need of resolution.

I have a Gallery in which I enter data - including a User created 'JobUnqID'. I am Patching the 'JobUnqID' to the List. I am uploading a document the an attachment control to a 'JobDocsLibrary'. The Flow is below. Where do I add the language the will Patch (as this is a new document) the appropriate and specific 'JobCQUnqID' along side the document in the Library as a result of the Patch / Flow action. I've gotten it to kinda work; but its overwritting the wrong item (or multiple wrong items) in the Library.

Flow:

When and item is created

Site

List Name: JobsLibrary

Get Files (properties only)

Site (same as above)

Library Name: JobsDocLibrary

(Both of the above have a column for 'JobCQUnqID'; the 'JobCQUnqID' is being created in the PowerApps Gallery and Patched to the 'JobsList')

Apply to each

Value

Update file properties

Site

Library Name: 'JobDocsLibrary'

Id: SpID (items('Apply_to_each_2')?[ID]

JobCQUnqID: (items(('Apply_to_each_2')?['JobCQUnqID']

Comment: Please describe how the file is created in the Document Library? Are you passing the attachments from PowerApps to a Flow? If the file is created using a Flow, you can update other meta data properties of that document from within the same Flow

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Yes, the document is uploaded to the Library through a flow. I've created a test Library and test Flow. The test Flow is updating the desired meta data into the appropriate Library column, as desired. However, the update is being done matching the line Item fromt he List to the Library - the 'CQUnqID' in Line 7 of the List is updated to 'Item 7' in the Library. I need the 'CQUnqID' from the List to follow the doc to the Library and 'CQUnqID' becomes the 'ID' for the document in the Library and data in the List; right now List 'ID' updates Library 'ID'. Not desired.

Comment: I think the pseudo code would be: Get a List item (say ID=1), Find the corresponding Document in the Document Library and then update Doc.[CQUnqID]=List.[CQUnqID]. Do you have any other column between the List and the Library that links them?

Comment: No, there is no other connective tissue between the Library and the List. Which is why I need that 'CQUnqID' sent over from the List to the Library. Its the existing documents that are the issue. This wouldn't be and issue if I was starting from scratch.